# How to validate a success text message which is in two lines in Specflow

Tags: c#, specflow

I am trying to validate a message generated by the application after creating or deleting a value.

I tried capturing the input from application and the success message from application is as follows:-

Example:

```
"This is a -\r\nText Message."
```

My input in specflow:-

```
Then user verifies "This is a -r nText Message." ->Does not work
```

Tried this as well-

```
Then user verifies "This is a -\r\nText Message." ->Does not work and returns text "This is a -\\\r\\\nText Message."
```

Please help.

HTML CODE:-

```html
<article class="alertify-log alertify-log-success alertify-log-show">
    This is a -
    <br>
    Text Message.
<article/>
```

My Code:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//article[@class='alertify-log alertify-log-success alertify-log-show']")]
public IWebElement AlertMessage;

public static void(string Message)
{
    string VerifyMessage = commonPage.AlertMessage.Text;
    Assert.AreEqual(Message, VerifyMessage);
    Console.WriteLine(VerifyMessage );
}
```

Comment: I tried cleaning up and formatting your code as best as I could. There are syntax errors and what appears to be code from two different classes in one snippet. It is almost impossible to answer this is question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do a replace.

```
var test = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//article[@class='alertify-log alertify-log-success alertify-log-show']")).Text.Replace("-\r\n", "");
```

This will return:

```
    "This is a Text Message."
```

So in your code, try this:

change your step to look for the text without the "-\r\n"

```
var Message = "This is a Text Message.";  

[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//article[@class='alertify-log alertify-log-success alertify-log-show']")]

public IWebElement AlertMessage;

public static void(string Message)
{
string VerifyMessage = commonPage.AlertMessage.Text.Replace("-\r\n", "");
Assert.AreEqual(Message, VerifyMessage);
Console.WriteLine(VerifyMessage );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead of a normal parameter a DocString (https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Gherkin/Gherkin-Reference.html#doc-strings) parameter. With that, you can specify multiline- strings

Your step looks then like this:

```
Then user verifies 
    """
    This is a
    Text Message.
    """
```

You can access this multiline string as a normal parameter:

```cs
[Then("user verifies")]
public void BindingMethod(string parameter)
{
    //your code
}
```